# Loop outside doesn't work

Tags: mysql, loops, procedure

How to loop one inside the other?............................

But the loop outside doesn't work. Only the loop inside runs................

I have these tables: ........................

people:

```
 ________________
| code | name    |
|   1  | Carlos  |
|   2  | Charles |
|   3  | Mary    |
|   4  | Jhon    |
|   5  | Jen     |
-----------------
```

classes:

```
  ________________
| code | desc       |
|   1  | Java       |
|   2  | PHP        |
|   3  | Perl       |
|   4  | Python     |
|   5  | Javascript |
-------------------
```

These is the part of my procedure:

```
DECLARE v_cdclass INT;
DELCARE v_codperson INT;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp1;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp1 
(
  id  INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  
  cdfunc         INT(11),
  class           INT
); 
OPEN R; 
    loop0: LOOP
         FETCH R INTO v_codperson; 
            IF done2 THEN
               LEAVE loop0;
            END IF;

            BLOCO2: BEGIN

              OPEN classes;      
                 loop1: LOOP    
                    FETCH classes INTO v_cdclass ;  
                    IF done1 THEN
                        LEAVE loop1;
                    END IF;
                        INSERT INTO temp1 
                        ( cdfunc,  class )
                        VALUES 
                        ( v_codperson , v_cdclass);  
                  END LOOP loop1;   
                CLOSE classes;        

            END BLOCO2;
    END LOOP ;      
CLOSE R; 
SELECT * FROM temp1;
```

Comment: I've edit your question a bit for clarity. Please do also [edit] it and state clearly what you mean by "doesn't work". What happens when you run your code? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with? You may also want to take the [tour] of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```sql
DELIMITER \\

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_test`\\
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `classes`, `people`\\

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `people` (
  `code` SERIAL,
  `name` VARCHAR(25)
)\\

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `classes` (
  `code` SERIAL,
  `desc` VARCHAR(25)
)\\

INSERT INTO `people`
  (`name`)
VALUES
  ('Carlos'), ('Charles'),
  ('Mary'), ('Jhon'),
  ('Jen')\\

INSERT INTO `classes`
  (`desc`)
VALUES
  ('Java'), ('PHP'),
  ('Perl'), ('Python'),
  ('Javascript')\\

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_test`()
BEGIN
  DECLARE `v_cdclass` BIGINT UNSIGNED;
  DECLARE `v_codperson` BIGINT UNSIGNED;
  DECLARE `done2` BOOL;
  DECLARE `R` CURSOR FOR
    SELECT `code` FROM `people`;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET `done2` := TRUE;
  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `temp1`;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temp1` (
    `id`  SERIAL,
    `cdfunc` BIGINT UNSIGNED,
    `class` BIGINT UNSIGNED
  ); 
  OPEN `R`;
    `loop0`: LOOP
      FETCH `R` INTO `v_codperson`;
      IF `done2` THEN
        LEAVE `loop0`;
      END IF;
      `BLOCO2`: BEGIN
        DECLARE `done1` BOOL;
        DECLARE `classes` CURSOR FOR
          SELECT DISTINCT `code` FROM `classes`;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET `done1` := TRUE;
        OPEN `classes`;
        `loop1`: LOOP
          FETCH `classes` INTO `v_cdclass`;
          IF `done1` THEN
            LEAVE `loop1`;
          END IF;
          INSERT INTO `temp1`
            (`cdfunc`, `class`)
          VALUES 
            (`v_codperson` , `v_cdclass`);
        END LOOP `loop1`;   
        CLOSE `classes`;        
      END `BLOCO2`;
    END LOOP `loop0`;
  CLOSE R; 
  SELECT `cdfunc`, `class`
  FROM `temp1`;
END\\

CALL `sp_test`\\

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_test`\\
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `temp1`\\
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `classes`, `people`\\

DELIMITER ;
```

See [Rextester](http://rextester.com/HWT41336).